# Create Bitmap in C

Tags: c, bitmap

I'm trying to create a Bitmap that shows the flightpath of a bullet.

```
    int drawBitmap(int height, int width, Point* curve, char* bitmap_name)
{

  int image_size = width * height * 3;
  int padding = width - (width % 4);

  struct _BitmapFileheader_ BMFH;
  struct _BitmapInfoHeader_ BMIH;

  BMFH.type_[1] = 'B';
  BMFH.type_[2] = 'M';
  BMFH.file_size_ = 54 + height * padding;
  BMFH.reserved_1_ = 0;
  BMFH.reserved_2_ = 0;
  BMFH.offset_ = 54;

  BMIH.header_size_ = 40;
  BMIH.width_ = width;
  BMIH.height_ = height;
  BMIH.colour_planes_ = 1;
  BMIH.bit_per_pixel_ = 24;
  BMIH.compression_ = 0;
  BMIH.image_size_ = image_size + height * padding;
  BMIH.x_pixels_per_meter_ = 2835;
  BMIH.y_pixels_per_meter_ = 2835;
  BMIH.colours_used_ = 0;
  BMIH.important_colours_ = 0;

  writeBitmap(BMFH, BMIH, curve, bitmap_name);

    }

void* writeBitmap(struct _BitmapFileheader_ file_header, 
  struct _BitmapInfoHeader_ file_infoheader, void* pixel_data, char* file_name)
{
  FILE* image = fopen(file_name, "w");

  fwrite((void*)&file_header, 1, sizeof(file_header), image);
  fwrite((void*)&file_infoheader, 1, sizeof(file_infoheader), image);
  fwrite((void*)pixel_data, 1, sizeof(pixel_data), image);
  fclose(image);

  return 0;

}
```

Curve is the return value from the function which calculates the path. It points at an array of Points, which is a struct of x and y coordinates. 
I don't really know how to "put" the data into the Bitmap correctly.
I just started programming C recently and I'm quite lost at the moment.

Comment: to start, a .bmp file use little endian formatting.. so, for instance, the first two char 'B' and 'M' are actually in the order 'M','B'.  Each field follows the same little endian formatting.  So the assignment statement, in the code, may or may not result in the correct ordering of the bytes of a field, depending on the underlying hardware.

Comment: when using a struct, where different fields have different sizing, there will be padding bytes inserted between the defined fields, as necessary, for alignment of the next field to the appropriate address boundary.  This padding (has nothing to do with the image line padding to make each line a multiple of 4) will result in a invalid .bmp file.  To achieve the correct byte ordering and no compiler added padding, the proper method is to define the structs as groups of bytes (char) and place each byte individually

Comment: @user3629249 `BMFH.type_` looks like an array so the "BM" id bytes *are* the right way round. But the array indices are wrong. Should be `BMFH.type_[0] = 'B'; BMFH.type_[1] = 'M';`

Comment: leading underscore '_' in names is a very bad idea, because the compiler generates instances of each name, with a leading underscore, so confusion can/will result.  suggest remove the leading underscores from the struct names

Comment: Recently, there are several questions on here that resulted in the correct coding of a .bmp file.  You should search for questions that include 'BMP'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know about taking up any slack space in each pixel row, but I see a problem in your calculation. Each pixel row must have `length % 4 == 0`. So with 3 bytes per pixel (24-bit)

```
length = ((3 * width) + 3) & -4;  // -4 as I don't know the int size, say 0xFFFFFFFC
```

Look up the structure of a bitmap - perhaps you already have. Declare (or allocate) an image byte array size `height * length` and fill it with zeros. Parse the bullet trajectory and find the range of `x` and `y` coordinates. Scale these to the bitmap size `width` and `height`. Now parse the bullet trajectory again, scaling the coordinates to `xx` and `yy`, and write three `0xFF` bytes (you specified 24-bit colour) into the correct place in the array for each bullet position.

```
if (xx >= 0 && xx < width && yy >= 0 && yy < height) {
    index = yy * length + xx * 3;
    bitmap [index]     = 0xFF;
    bitmap [index + 1] = 0xFF;
    bitmap [index + 2] = 0xFF;
}
```

Finally save the bitmap info, header and image data to file. When that works, you can refine your use of colour.