# Basic Image display of 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, image

As part of a project I am doing in C, it would be helpful to produce a visual representation of the data I am working with.

My question is: for some dynamically declared array:

```
double *foo;
foo = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*x*y);

for (i=0;i<x;i++)
    for (j=0;j<y;j++)
        foo[i*y+j] = someValue;
```

If the data has some max/min value (lets say max = 100.0 and min = 5.0), what is the simplest way to represent this data graphically?

I would like some method of displaying each number as a gradient of some color, for example, the max would be black and the min would be white.

An output of a Bitmap image for example would be a good as I need to do this for multiple arrays.

thanks.

Comment: The most important thing you would need to figure out is how to map values to colors, which is more of an art than a science. Once you've decided that, it's just a matter of writing the data into a file in the [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: The arrays are large so 1 pixel per value is fine. For the colour mapping, if BMP uses RGB I could just use R[x]G[x]B[x] where x is a value representative of its position from 0-255 from the values min-max value. I have no experience with outputting into image files however

Comment: The [PGM file format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) is very simple if you only need a greyscale image. It has minimal header information and you can write raw pixel data as-is from a 2D array of `char` or `short`. Keep in mind with image files the convention is to use low values as black and high values for white.

Comment: I answered a previous question about placing a bullet position on a bitmap to file. It needs a thoughtful approach, and although the question doesn't answer everything, you may get something useful. The main things with bitmaps, are 1) making sure the endianness of the header fields is correct, 2) making sure the header struct you use is correctly packed/aligned, and 3) being aware that each raster row must have a byte length divisible by 4 (pad bytes are ignored). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362625/create-bitmap-in-c/27364496#27364496

Comment: I really only need a simple implementation (greyscale) as the display is for a threshold matrix (so I will be looking for a specific shape with density areas). The PGM format seems promising, I will try it out with some sample data and report back, thanks

Comment: Once you have a `PGM` (which is great advice), you can use ImageMagick to make a JPEG or PNG like this `convert input.pgm output.jpg` or `convert input.pgm -resize 600x600 output.png`

Comment: With bitmaps, a greyscale is more complicated as you have to set up the header with a palette lookup, unless you make each of the RGB components of a 24-bit map equal.